# Pass a nested route to data-source

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Before having my model nested I used to pass a url to data-source like this:

```
data-source="<%= keywords_url(format: "json") %>
```

Now I have keywords nested under projects:

```
project_keywords GET    /projects/:project_id/keywords(.:format)
```

How do I need to change it in order to make it work.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will now have the url helper `project_keywords_url`.

You need to pass in the project like so:

```
project_keywords_url(@project, format: "json")
```

or project_id

```
project_keywords_url(project_id, format: "json")
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
data-source="<%= project_keywords_path(your_project_id, format: "json") %>
```

And you have an instance variable `@project` in your view, you can also write it like this:

```
data-source="<%= project_keywords_path(@project, format: "json") %>
```

Don't hesitate to have a look at the guide: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html